# Shower pebble tile grout cracking

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

Picture of cracking grout around pebbles. When we step on it while taking a shower it makes a squishing sound like water being pushed out.  What's the best solution? can I remove the cracked grout and re-grout?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The squishing sound is a bad sound. That means water is underneath the pebble tiles and is possibly rotting out the sub floor. You'll need to break up some of the flooring, possibly along the grout lines and determine the extent of any damage. You'll need to repair any damage and then add the pebbles back and then you can re grout and re caulk.

Comment: That's the answer to this question. For answers to the question of "how do I fix the problems I find?", ask new questions about each of the issues encountered. _Forestalls an ongoing flood of questions in comments._